# Checking a bag is Null or not inside foreach in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

**I am joining 3 tables and inside foreach i need to check wheather  ReadStagingData bag is null.**
Below is the code

```
ReadStagingData = Load 'Staging_data.csv' Using PigStorage(',') As     (PL_Posn_id:int,Brok_org_dly:double,Brok_org_ptd:double);

ReadPriorData = Load 'ptd.csv' Using PigStorage(',') As (PL_Posn_id:int,Brok_org_ptd:double);

ReadPriorFunctional = Load 'Functional.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (PL_Posn_id:int,Brok_fun_ptd:double,Brok_fun_ltd:double);

JoinDS1 = JOIN ReadPriorData BY PL_Posn_id,ReadPriorFunctional BY PL_Posn_id;

JoinDS2 = JOIN ReadStagingData by PL_Posn_id Left OUTER,JoinDS1 BY      ReadPriorData::PL_Posn_id;

X = Foreach JoinDS2 {
    **test = (NOT(IsEmpty(ReadStagingData))); //Error on this line**
    GENERATE test,ReadStagingData::PL_Posn_id,
    ReadStagingData::Brok_org_dly,
   (ReadStagingData::Brok_org_ptd is not null ? ReadStagingData::Brok_org_ptd:ReadPriorData::Brok_org_ptd+ReadStagingData::Brok_org_dly);
};

Dump X;
```

When i am running the above code i am getting error INVALID PROJECTION ReadStagingData.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In your relation `X`, `ReadStagingData` is not a bag.  The notation `ReadStagingData::Brok_org_dly` does not indicate projection from a bag; it is a top-level field which is named that way after the `JOIN` in order to ensure each field is named uniquely.  So `ReadStagingData` is just a prefix.

In addition, I'm not sure why you're trying to check that -- because you're doing a `LEFT OUTER` join, there won't be any records in `X` without a corresponding record in `ReadStagingData`.  If you were doing a `RIGHT OUTER` join, that would be different.

If you were intending to do a `RIGHT OUTER` join, and you wanted to check to see if the fields from `ReadStagingData` were `NULL`, I would do:

```
rsdIsNull = ReadStagingData::PL_Posn_id IS NULL;
```